# i am using codeigniter 2.1.3 and i have the images outside the website in the /home folder and cannot show the images

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeigniter 2.1.3 and I have the images outside the website in the /home folder and cannot show the images.

```
 <img src="<?php echo img('/home/pedro/iagora.jpg');?>" title="" alt="avatar_<?php echo $project['id']; ?>" width="120" height="80"/>
```

I have tried:

```
     <img src="<?php echo '/home/pedro/iagora.jpg';?>" title="" alt="avatar_<?php echo $project['id']; ?>" width="120" height="80"/>
```

And:

```
     <img src="/home/pedro/iagora.jpg" title="" alt="avatar_<?php echo $project['id']; ?>" width="120" height="80"/>
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are outside of the web root you can't access them over HTTP normally. You will need to write a PHP script that outputs the image for you:

```
<img src="/get_image.php?i=iagora.jpg" title="">
```

`/get_image.php` would be the PHP file that retrieves the image and outputs it for you. The `i` parameter would be the name of the image you want.

That file would look something like:

```
<?php
    $file_name = $_GET['i'];
    $file = '/home/pedro/' . $file_name;

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create the folder "assets" in your base folder. In "assets" you will store js, css, uploads images and all others. In this form you can organize better your aplication

And after that, you can load the images with base_url().
for example:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/your_folder/your_image.jpg" title="" alt="avatar_<?php echo $project['id']; ?>" width="120" height="80" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i saved the script file on the root of the website and now its working

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$images_thumb_dir.$project['avatar'];?>" title="" alt="avatar_<?php echo $project['id']; ?>" width="120" height="80"/>
```

thanks 
Pedro